# Get Attributes of a Func

Tags: c#, reflection, func

I need to check an incoming `Func<TIn, TOut>` for a specific attribute.

So far I have:

```
var methodInfo = cachedMethod.GetMethodInfo();
var isCachable = methodInfo.CustomAttributes.
                       Any(x => x.AttributeType == typeof(CachedAttribute));
```

However I'm finding that the CustomAttributes property is empty.

What's the proper way to find the attributes applied to an incoming func? In my case the func is a static method in another class.

**Update**

Here's a small sample showing how I'm trying to use this:

**The HTML helper:**

```
        public static IHtmlString CachedPartial<TModel>(this HtmlHelper helper, 
          string partialName, 
          TModel model, 
          Func<string, string> cachedMethod)
        {
            var methodInfo = cachedMethod.GetMethodInfo();
            var isCachable = methodInfo.IsDefined(typeof (CachedAttribute));

            if (!isCachable)
            {
                throw new Exception("...");
            }

            return new MvcHtmlString(cachedMethod("foo"));
        }
```

**The cached method**

```
        [Cached]
        public static string GenrateSiteMapGraphHtml(string siteCode)
        {
            return "Foo";
        }
```

**This is being called from a Razor view:**

```
@Html.CachedPartial("Foo", 
                     Model, 
                     HtmlHelperExtensions.GenrateSiteMapGraphHtml)
```

Comment: It would help if you could show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. Do you definitely need to use `CustomAttributes` rather than just `IsDefined`, btw? (It seems unlikely that this is loaded in a reflection-only context...)

Comment: I wasn't aware of `IsDefined` so I can replace the `CustomAttributes` part with that. I still get `false` returned when checking for the attribute however. I'll post a sample program.

Comment: Have you tried using `Delegate.Method` instead of the `GetMethodInfo` extension method? I don't know what the difference is, if any...

Comment: Yeah I've just tried this: `cachedMethod.Method.IsDefined(typeof (CachedAttribute));`

Comment: Again, a short but complete program would really help - can you demonstrate this outside ASP.NET for example? Trying it with a console app would be easier for us to experiment with.

Comment: I'll upload something in a moment. Funnily in the context of this console app, everything works as expected. O_o

Comment: Right. If you can debug into it (in MVC), maybe have a look at whether `cachedMethod.Method.GetCustomAttributes(true)` returns *any* attributes... maybe it's a type coalescing issue?

Comment: I'll have a look into that now. In the meantime, here's the repo: https://github.com/JamieDixon/FunkyAttributes

Comment: I'm one step closer. It looks like the attribute in question is a Postsharp MethodInterceptionAspect attribute. When I create a custom attribute and check for it, it's there. There must be something about this postsharp attribute that I'm unaware of.

Comment: Ah, that may well be part of it. Try going back to your LINQ "Any" query, but just using the *name* of the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I may not quite understand what is your problem, but I'll suggest two things:

1. You need to be sure that CustomAttributes isn't empty, use

   if (methodInfo.CustomAttributes!=NULL) //or whatever is analogue of NULL for that type of property
      {/*some action*/}
2. You can't figure out *why* is this property empty. The first thing to check is visibility.

> In my case the func is a static method in another class

So go and check out if that class is visible for the area of code where you are trying to invoke that static method

Comment: Based on @jon-skeet comment, that abstract comparison with "NULL" in my answer should be replaced with IsDefined.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The visibility of the method seems fine and I can execute it no problem. I just need to check for an existing attribute (which in this specific case I know exists).